# how to handle yes or no of ajax confirmation dialog

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

in the belwo code I am trying to create ajax call when the user access the following url as shown below:

```
    "/product/remove/" + idx,
```

I want to show a dialog with "Yes" and "No", and this dialog should appear only when the user enters the previous url and click enter and before the logic of the controller that handles the remove or delete action gets executed, that's why I used "beforeSend" attribute in $.ajax call below.

I googled several posts regarding how to integrate and create confirmation dialog with ajax call and spring MVC, however most of the hits i get need further clarifications.

what I want to achieve is, when the user clicks Yes, the controller shown in the code belwo should execute normally. when the user clicks No, nothing should happen, only the dialog
should disappear.

please find my attempt below, and please help me to achieve it

**code_1**:

```
@<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Ajax confirm delete prodcut</title>
<script
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


$('#confirmremoveform').click(function() {
var idx = $('#idx').val();
var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (ans) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "/product/remove/" + idx,
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#modal-book").modal("show");
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
          },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
});
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<fieldset>
    <legend>confirmremove</legend>
    <input type="button" value="confirmremove" id="confirmremoveform" />
    <br/>
    <span id="result0"></span>
    </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product/remove")
public class RemoveProductPageController {

public final static String sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName = "removeProductFromList";

public final static String CONTROLLER_URL = "/product/remove";
public final static String DO_REMOVE_HANDLER_METHOD_URL = CONTROLLER_URL + "/{idx}";

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{idx}", 
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> doRemove(@Validated @Size(min = 0) @PathVariable(required = true) int idx,
        Model model) {

    Product productToBeRemove = productService.getProductFromListByIdx(idx);
    if (productToBeRemove == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("no product is avaialble at index:" + idx, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    model.addAttribute(RemoveProductPageController.sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName, productToBeRemove);
    productService.removeProdcutFromListBxIdx(idx);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("product removed from index: " + idx, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace following logic

```
var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (ans) {
    //your all code
}

// with a single liner
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?")) {}
```

Comment: thaks..but i want in case of YES is clicked..the controller continue execution normally, in No is clicked, nothing occurs only the dislaog disappears..is it the case

Comment: Interesting, you mean confirm popup isn't disappearing OR that also does a delete ?
Its really weird that I am not getting you at this point.

Comment: hi..would you please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974702/how-to-execute-the-controller-based-on-input-to-a-pop-up-or-dialog-from-ajax    it is almost the same topic..i will delete this post