# How to execute the controller based on input to a pop-up or dialog from ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

in the belwo code "code_2" I have a controller that applies http method DELETE, to remove a specific product based on the provided id. 
in "code_1", I am trying to create ajax call that shows or present to the user a dialog or pop-up with YES and NO BEFORE the controller in code_2 is executed. in other words, when the client call

```
/product/remove/2
```

he should be presented with a popup or dialog with YES and No. When he clicks YES, then the controller in code_2 should be executed normally. If he click NO, nothing should happen..only the dialog or the pop-up disappears.

For the pop-up or the dialog, I did the following as shown below:

```
<body>
    <form action="http://www.google.com/search">
        <input type="text" name="q" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to search Google?')"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

i could not not find a form with YES and NO buttons...can you help me to correct it

I have implemneted the below code_1 and code_2.

please let me know if the code is correct or needs to be modified...i do not have access to server moreover, I am new to ajax and spring mvc technologies.

**code_1**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Ajax confirm delete prodcut</title>
<script
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


$('#confirmremoveform').click(function() {
var idx = $('#idx').val();
var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (ans) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "/product/remove/" + idx,
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#modal-book").modal("show");
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $("#onsuccessfuldelete").text(data);
          },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
});
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="http://www.google.com/search">
        <input type="text" name="q" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to search Google?')"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**code_2**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product/remove")
public class RemoveProductPageController {

public final static String sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName = "removeProductFromList";

public final static String CONTROLLER_URL = "/product/remove";
public final static String DO_REMOVE_HANDLER_METHOD_URL = CONTROLLER_URL + "/{idx}";

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{idx}", 
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> doRemove(@Validated @Size(min = 0) @PathVariable(required = true) int idx,
        Model model) {

    Product productToBeRemove = productService.getProductFromListByIdx(idx);
    if (productToBeRemove == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("no product is avaialble at index:" + idx, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    model.addAttribute(RemoveProductPageController.sRemoveProductFromListAttributeName, productToBeRemove);
    productService.removeProdcutFromListBxIdx(idx);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("product removed from index: " + idx, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Comment: where is `#confirmremoveform` in above code ?

Comment: i found an example using it as it is ..i am still learning it..may be you can guid me

Comment: okay , also from where are you getting `idx` , also does your records display in table format i.e: each row in table have that `delete` button ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SWAL](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)(SweetAlert). It is a customizable replacement for javascript popups.

There are a lot of options you can choose from.

Example:

JSP,
On click of your delete button

```
$('#[idOfDeleteButton]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record',
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true
            }).then(function () {
               //execute once user confirms else nothing happens
                var deleteLink = "[link to controller]?id="+[idTobeDeleted];
                $.ajax({
                    url: deleteLink ,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (res) {
                       //res is the string returned in the controller
                        if (res === "Success!") {
                            swal({
                                title: res,
                                text: "Delete Successful!",
                                type: 'success'
                            });

                        } else {
                            swal({
                                title: res,
                                text: "Deleting record Failed!",
                                type: 'error'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
});
```